# Android version of ShazamKit performs poorly compared to the official Shazam app

Tags: android, shazam, shazamkit

In my Flutter project, I implemented the ShazamKit API for both iOS and Android, using the [flutter_shazam_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_shazam_kit) package.

Following each step as described [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_shazam_kit), I implemented the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_shazam_kit/example), and managed to make it work on both Android and iOS.

That being said, I tested it with [that song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gn6e57vOUac) (I know, it's some weird stuff, but that's the purpose of the test), and here are the results:

- the official Shazam app recognizes it instantly
- ShazamKit on iOS recognizes it correctly, though after 3 to 4 seconds
- ShazamKit on Android doesn't manage to recognize it at all, even after trying it multiple times

More importantly: I made the test with the official Shazam app and the Android version of the [flutter_shazam_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_shazam_kit) example on the **same device**.

I made some research and found out that [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712483) where it says that it could come from the `maximumQuerySignatureDuration`, but I already use the maximum allowed expiration delay, which is exactly 15777000 seconds, but still not working. Not sure if it refers to that or not, though.

Any help would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it was because the package uses a wrong sample rate for the Android part (41000 Hz instead of 44100 Hz for example).